# Summing up a list of numbers with a twist

Tags: python

I want to sum up a list of numbers excluding 6 and 9, and every number in between them.
**The twist** is the list has multiple 6s and 9s.

- Numbers should only be **excluded** if it is between 6 and 9, and vice versa between 6 and 9), only in this order .
  ([6,n1,n2,n3,n4,9]or[9,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,6])
- numbers between two 6s [6,n1,n2,n3,6] and
  two 9s [9,n1,n2,n3,n4,9] should be **included**.

Example:
list1= [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]
expected result : sum(1,2,3,4,7,2,4,4,3,2,1) = 33

---

This is the solution for the problem without the twist:

```
def sum6(nums):
    total = 0 
    between6And9 = False 
    for i in nums: 
        if i == 6: 
            between6And9 = True
        elif i == 9: 
            between6And9 = False
        elif not between6And9: 
            total+= i
    return total
```

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: Not an answer but a tiny suggestion: name your variables for what they stand for, not what they are.  In this case it's better to rename `flag` to `between6And9` or such.  Once you do that, it's easy to spot that your `elif` test is done too soon and thus incorrect (you prob. want to check for 9 first and only then do the summation in the else).

Comment: You need to clarify more what you expect. How should the influence of multiple 6 and 9s affect your result. Currently we are left guessing. Maybe you want a second `subsub` variable that you fill up and either add to your total sum or discard. However currently cannot tell how you want to handle the exception cases.

Comment: @Daraan .  i want to exclude all numbers between each occurrence of 6 and 9, and then summarize the remaining numbers.

Comment: @babypython By "summarize" you really mean "to sum up" the remaining numbers right?

Comment: @S.B yes.......

Comment: @babypython  To me is not clear: Do you want to exclude digits between 9...9 as well? What about 6...[end of list] without any 9 after, count them or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? If you're looking for help solving this, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? Check out [ask] for tips. Either way, I agree with previous comments; for me, it's not clear what you mean by "between". It'd help to show what the list would look like after filtering out the numbers you don't want.

Comment: @CtrlZ . i edited the question and mentioned the expected result .

Comment: @Daraan . i edited the question and cleared that up .
(only 6 and 9 and vice versa )

Comment: In your no-twist code, `between6And9` becomes true at 6 and false at 9. But in your twist-example, it apparently also becomes true at 9 (since you exclude the 4,5 after it). What is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the crucial part was that also 9...6 needs to be omitted, too.
Using two flags for both cases, adding numbers at

- ...(6|9)
- 6...6 or 9...9
- (6|9) ...

```py
list1= [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]

def twistersum(list1):
    the_sum = 0
    temp = 0
    saw6 = saw9 = False
    for i in list1:
        if i == 6:
            if saw6 or (not saw6 and not saw9): # "or" handles occurrence of first 6 in list
                the_sum += temp
            temp = 0
            saw6 = True
            saw9 = False
        elif i == 9:
            if saw9 or (not saw6 and not saw9): # "or" handles occurrence of first 6 in list
                the_sum += temp
            temp = 0
            saw6 = False
            saw9 = True
        else:
            temp += i
    the_sum += temp # sum last remaining numbers at end of list
    return the_sum

print(twistersum(list1))
# Output 33
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a second list in which you zero-out the items at positions that are excluded.  Then using sum() on that list will produce the desired result.

To clear out the excluded items, you can go through each position that has a 6 or a 9 and find the next position that has the closing marker (15 - n).  This will give you the range of item indexes to clear out.  However, if that range contains the starting number (e.g. [6,..,6...],9 ) then you should not exclude it and wait to reach the other number to make a decision.

This can be implemented using basic code structures:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]   


included = list1.copy()
for i,n in enumerate(list1):              # get each number and its index
    if n in (6,9) and 15-n in list1[i:]:  # identify begining of exclusion
        e = i + list1[i:].index(15-n)+1   # find end of exclusion
        if n not in list1[i+1:e]:         # ignore 9..9 and 6..6
            included[i:e] = [0]*(e-i)     # exclude range by replacing with 0
result = sum(included)
        
print(result) # 33
```

For a bit more advanced version of this, you can use accumulate to build a list of starting marker and a list of ending marker for each position.  Then use sum() on a list comprehension combining the original list with these starts and ends. This will provide the information on the  previous and next marker for each number.  If the number and the previous and next markers contain both a 6 and a 9, then the number is part of a 6..9 or 9..6 pattern and needs to be excluded from the sum.

```
from itertools import accumulate

*starts, = accumulate(list1[:-1],   lambda a,n:n if n in (6,9) else a)
*ends,   = accumulate(list1[:0:-1], lambda a,n:n if n in (6,9) else a)
result   = sum( n for n,s,e in zip(list1,[0]+starts,ends[::-1]+[0])
                if {6,9} - {s,n,e} )

print(result) # 33
```

Illustration of how it works:

```
# list1,  [0]+starts,  ends[::-1]+[0],  X/.,  included

# X = clear if 6 and 9 both in s,n,e
# . = keep if 6 or 9 absent from s,n,e: Truthy of {6,9}-{s,n,e}

 n [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 9, 7, 2, 4, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 2, 1]
 s [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9]
 e [6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
 #  .  .  .  .  X  X  X  X  X  .  .  .  X  X  X  X  X  X  X, .  .  .  .
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: as a beginner this code is a bit advanced for me  . given your explaination this shoud return the correct result except result shown in the code is 29 while it should be 33 . 
list1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]  
sum (1,2,3,4,7,2,4,4,3,2,1) = 33

Comment: Reworked my answer to match your revised question.

Comment: i can't thank you enough for the time and effort you've put into this .i appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

I understand this way: A list consists of many single digit numbers. Let us assume the iteration(loop) starts from the first element of the list. Every number of the list is added. Once if 6 comes in the list, from next number we should stop adding, but iteration will simply go on.  Once 9 comes in the iteration, again start adding the numbers. There can be numbers of 6 and 9. All numbers between 6 and should be left unadded. But 6 and 9 should be added. Please follow my solution step by step. You'll understand and there is no need of further explanation:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]
total = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i-1] == 6:
        j = i
        
        while j >= i:
            if list1[j] == 9:
                i = j
                break
            j += 1
    
    total = total + list1[i]
    i += 1
print(total) #output : 81
```

Edit:
For excluding 6 and 9 within the range but adding 6 and 9 if found anywhere else:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]
total = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i] == 6:
        j = i
        
        while j >= i:
            if list1[j] == 9:
                i = j+1
                break
            j += 1
    print(list1[i])
    
    total = total + list1[i]
    i += 1
print(total) #output : 51
```

For excluding 6 and 9 within the range but adding 6 and 9 also outside the range:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,3,5,9,7,2,4,9,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,2,1]
total = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i] == 6:
        j = i
        
        while j >= i:
            if list1[j] == 9:
                i = j+1
                break
            j += 1
    if list1[i] == 6 or list1[i] ==9:
        list1[i] = 0
    
    total = total + list1[i]
    i += 1
print(total) #output : 42
```

Comment: by far the closest solution for the expected result , except there are two issues . 
1- as i point out in the first line of question ,  6  and  9  should be excluded aswell . 
2- value of expected result should be 33 . even if you add 6s and 9s you get 72 but the result shown in the code is 81 .

Comment: @babypython, See my edited answer. Looks like there is some error in your addition. to confirm add a print command before `total = total + list1[i]`  with the same iteration so that you'll find what all the numbers are added. add `print(list1[i])` before `total = total + list1[i]` . I checked that as well.

Comment: As per your question, numbers between 6 and 9 should be omitted, and not between 9 and 6

Comment: i really appreciate the help . i got the answer.